# What goes inside of an html blockquote tag to indicate the author?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, blockquote

I have a blockquote tag, is there a semantic tag I could put inside for the author name? For example:

```
<blockquote>Anyone who has neber made a mistake has never tried anything new 
-<author>Einstein</author>
</blockquote>
```

`<author>` is not an actual html tag, is there any appropriate tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <blockquote>Anyone who has neber made a mistake has never tried anything new -
 <cite>Einstein</cite>
    </blockquote>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but according to html 5 doctor `cite is to refer to a person, generally in connection with some reference or as the source of a quote:
<!-- Not valid usage of cite in HTML5! -->
<p>As <cite>George R. R. Martin</cite> wrote in…</p>`

Comment: @TheGamer If I recall, on HTML5 Doctor you'll see your same question answered somewhere.